# ImportError: No module named 'cryptography'

Tags: python, windows, paramiko

I installed python 3.4 on windows 7 and when trying to use paramiko I get this error :

```
import paramiko

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko-2.0.2-py3.4.egg\paramiko\__init__.py", line 30, in module

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\paramiko-2.0.2-py3.4.egg\paramiko\transport.py", line 32, in module

ImportError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

I installed pycrypto-2.6.1.win but the problem persist.
Any help ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It turned out that it was a proxy problem.
It was blocking download.
I did

```
pip install cryptography
pip install paramiko
```

from a direct internet connection and it worked.
Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 9):

It's not [pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) the package you need in order to import paramiko, try this:

> pip install [paramiko](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/)

Comment: I did pip install paramiko so I got this error : Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connecion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(10060...))': /simple/cryptography/ Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography>=1.1 (froparamiko) (from versions: ) o matching distribution found for cryptography>=1.1 (from paramiko) so I installed it manually running the setup.py script

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the [cryptography module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography).

Normally, dependencies would've automatically got pulled in when you install paramiko using a package manager like pip. How did you install paramiko? Are you installing manually?

Comment: I did pip install paramiko so I got this error :

 Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connecion broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(10060...))': /simple/cryptography/
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography>=1.1 (froparamiko) (from versions: )
o matching distribution found for cryptography>=1.1 (from paramiko)

so I installed it manually running the setup.py script

Answer (score 0):

For me I had Amazon Linux 2023.

it has resolved by uninstall aws and awscli using pip.

```
pip uninstall aws
pip uninstall awscli
```

This has resolve the issue

```
pip install awscli
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use

```
pip install cryptography
pip install paramiko
```

That's it. Try now.